# Merge two objects but only existing properties

Tags: javascript

I have two objects. And I want to merge the two objects but only the property value who is only present to the first object.

```
   obj1 : {
        "name": "",
        "age": ""
   }

  obj2 : {
        "name": "Leo",
        "age": "14",
        "company": "aero",
        "shift": "night"
  }
```

The output I want to be is:

```
  obj1 : {
        "name": "Leo",
        "age": "14"
   }
```

The `company` and `shift` is no need to merge because that 2 property is not present in `obj1`.

The code I've done so far is:
   `Object.assign({}, obj1, obj2);`

But it's not give me the right output. What it gives is:

```
 merge : {
        "name": "Leo",
        "age": "14",
        "company": "aero",
        "shift": "night"
  }
```

Could someone help me how to achieve the output like this:

```
  merge : {
        "name": "Leo",
        "age": "14",
  }
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Loop over the properties in the first object. Bring in the value from the second object if it is there. By the way, this has nothing to do in particular with either TypeScript or Angular.

Comment: Yes. But I am trying to avoid looping if it's possible. It just makes the codes long.

Comment: You can't avoid looping, one way or another.

Comment: Object.assign also works for more than one level. All answers are solutions for one level. A solution for deep merge of only existing properties also matches the question‘s title, so we might better rephrase the title.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Assuming you only want enumerable properties, this is easily done with `Object.keys` and `in` (or `hasOwnProperty`):

```
Object.keys(obj2).forEach(function(key) {
    if (key in obj1) { // or obj1.hasOwnProperty(key)
        obj1[key] = obj2[key];
    }
});
```

Example:

```js
var obj1 = {
  "name": "",
  "age": ""
};

var obj2 = {
  "name": "Leo",
  "age": "14",
  "company": "aero",
  "shift": "night"
};

Object.keys(obj2).forEach(function(key) {
  if (key in obj1) { // or obj1.hasOwnProperty(key)
    obj1[key] = obj2[key];
  }
});
console.log(obj1);
```

Or in ES2015 syntax (since you mentioned `Object.assign`):

```
for (const key of Object.keys(obj2)) {
    if (key in obj1) { // or obj1.hasOwnProperty(key)
        obj1[key] = obj2[key];
    }
}
```

Or a more fluent approach, but revisits the keys that are in `obj1` (not that it's likely to matter:

```
Object.keys(obj2).filter(key => key in obj1).forEach(key => {
    obj1[key] = obj2[key];
});
```

Since `forEach` ignores the return value of its callback, we could even go further in the concise-land:

```
Object.keys(obj2).filter(key => key in obj1).forEach(key => obj1[key] = obj2[key]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will just test it and accept the answer later. Is there a way not use loop?

Comment: @Zero: `Object.assign` uses a loop too, it's just not in *your* code. No, there's nothing built-in that won't involve some kind of looping.

Comment: Okay I got it. Thanks for the sample also. I've learned new things from you.

Comment: what about nested properties ?

Comment: @addy - The OP didn't need to handle nested properties. If you do, put the logic in a function and, when the property value is an object, recurse.

Comment: This does not work on objects within objects: `var obj = {a: {prop1:"1", prop2:"2"}, b: "4"}`

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira - See my comment to addy above.

Comment: _.assign(obj1, _.pick(obj2, _.keys(obj1))); with lodash

Answer (score 7):

Here's a more functional approach using [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
const obj1 = {
  "name": "",
  "age": ""
};

const obj2 = {
  "name": "Leo",
  "age": "14",
  "company": "aero",
  "shift": "night"
};

const newObject = Object.keys(obj1)
  .reduce(function(accumulator, key) {
    accumulator[key] = obj2[key]
    return accumulator
  }, {});

console.log(newObject);
```

Or some fun with ES6

```
const newObject = Object.keys(obj1)
  .reduce((a, key) => ({ ...a, [key]: obj2[key]}), {});
```

Comment: Although it is not clear how the question wished to address this case: your ES6 example will overwrite obj1 values with `undefined` if the key does not exist in obj2. Easily fixed with `obj2[key] || obj1[key]`.

Answer (score 3):

**Update 2020**

```
const data = {a:1,b:2,b:3}
const form = {a:'',b:''}

for (const key in data) {
  if (key in form) {
    form[key] = data[key];
  }
}
console.log(form) // Output: {a:1,b:2}
```

Answer (score 2):

Based off [T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder) 's answer.

Here's a nested version of it:

```js
const mergeFunction = (obj1, obj2) => {
  Object.keys(obj2).forEach(function (key) {
    if (key in obj1) {
      if (typeof obj1[key] === 'object') {
        mergeFunction(obj1[key], obj2[key]);
      } else {
        obj1[key] = obj2[key];
      }
    }
  });
};
```

Personally I don't like mutating the objects themselves so here's the version I use:

```js
const mergeExisting = (obj1, obj2) => {
  const mutableObject1 = Object.assign({}, obj1);
  const mutableObject2 = Object.assign({}, obj2);

  mergeFunction(mutableObject1, mutableObject2);

  return mutableObject1;
};

const mergeFunction = (obj1, obj2) => {
  Object.keys(obj2).forEach(function (key) {
    if (key in obj1) {
      if (typeof obj1[key] === 'object') {
        mergeFunction(obj1[key], obj2[key]);
      } else {
        obj1[key] = obj2[key];
      }
    }
  });
};
```

### Usage

```js
const object1 = {
  name: 'test',
  addresses: [
    {
      country: '',
      postalCode: ''
    },
    {
      unitNumber: '',
      building: ''
    }
  ]
};

const object2 = {
  name: 'test',
  email: 'test@example.com',
  description: 'urgh',
  addresses: [
    {
      country: 'SG',
      block: '6',
      street: 'Raffles Boulevard',
      unitNumber: '01-01',
      postalCode: '039594',
      building: 'Marina Square'
    },
    {
      country: 'SG',
      block: '6',
      street: 'Raffles Boulevard',
      unitNumber: '02-01',
      postalCode: '039594',
      building: 'Marina Square'
    }
  ]
};


mergeFunction(object1, object2);

// OR

const result = mergeExisting(object1, object2);


// Output
expect(result).toEqual({
  name: 'test',
  addresses: [
    { country: 'SG', postalCode: '039594' },
    { unitNumber: '02-01', building: 'Marina Square' }
  ]
});
```

Comment: `if (typeof obj1[key] === 'object')` ===>`if (obj1[key] !== null && typeof obj1[key] === 'object') {`，because `typeof null` is `object`

Answer (score 0):

**Mutable**

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj2)) {
    if (obj1[key]) {
        obj1[key] = value;
    }
}
```

**Immutable**

```
const newObj = {};
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj1)) {
    newObj[key] = obj2[key] || value;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If you know the properties of the first object, you can use Typescript's [Object deconstruction](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/destructuring.html):

```
let obj2 = {
  "name": "Leo",
  "age": "14",
  "company": "aero",
  "shift": "night"
}
let { name, age } = obj2; // deconstruction
let merged = { name, age }; // shorthand object creation
```

If properties are unknown, you'll have to use loop, as suggested.

Comment: If you make that last line `Object.assign(obj1, {name, age})` this seems like a possible approach given the caveat. It does require those temporary vars, but...

Comment: This is not "TypeScript's" object deconstruction. It's just plain old ES6. Anyway, your solution won't work if one of the properties is missing from `obj2`.