# Merge two objects only if id in object 2 exists in object 1 in plain Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, merge

Got two objects:

```
master  = [ { "id": 411, "state": 1 },
            { "id": 2134, "state": 1 },
            { "id": 2135, "state": 0 },
            { "id": 2137, "state": 0 } ]

 zips = [ { "id": 411, "zip": "90201" },
          { "id": 412, "zip": "90201" },
          { "id": 2134, "zip": "90201" },
          { "id": 2137, "zip": "90201" } ]
```

I'd like to merge them together *only* if the id in zips exists in devices.  Using the above data, the result should be:

```
master  = [ { "id": 411, "state": 1, "zip": "90201" },
            { "id": 2134, "state": 1, "zip": "90201" },
            { "id": 2135, "state": 0 },
            { "id": 2137, "state": 0, "zip": "90201" } ]
```

id: 412 is zips is 'skipped' because it's not in the devices object.

I've looked at looping through functions like Object.assign or merging with ... , but they have undesirable results (like adding the id 412 above because it exists in the second object)

Any hints or tips or better places to look are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does this post help you → https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40573555/merge-two-objects-but-only-existing-properties?

Comment: `master.map(o=>({...o,...zips.find(z=>z.id===o.id)}));`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge two objects but only existing properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40573555/merge-two-objects-but-only-existing-properties), or [Merge two array of objects based on a key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46849286/merge-two-array-of-objects-based-on-a-key)

Comment: @jabaa correct!  good catch.  question edited accordingly.   Just got used to pulling JSON into an object via a microservice and calling it still JSON.  :P

Comment: @zrna - almost!  but that appears to remove and differences and keeps only the same entries between the two objects.

Comment: seriously ... `master.map(o=>({...o,...zips.find(z=>z.id===o.id)}));` - of course, that won't change master :p - if you want to mutate master ... `master.forEach((o,i,a)=>a[i]={...o,...zips.find(z => z.id === o.id)});`

Comment: @JaromandaX - doh!  I keep forgetting about .map in my old age!  Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily achieve the result using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
const result = master.map((obj) => ({
  ...obj,
  ...zips.find((o) => o.id === obj.id),
}));
```

```js
master = [
  { id: 411, state: 1 },
  { id: 2134, state: 1 },
  { id: 2135, state: 0 },
  { id: 2137, state: 0 },
];

zips = [
  { id: 411, zip: "90201" },
  { id: 412, zip: "90201" },
  { id: 2134, zip: "90201" },
  { id: 2137, zip: "90201" },
];

const result = master.map((obj) => {
  const { id } = obj;
  const objThatExist = zips.find((o) => o.id === id);
  return { ...obj, ...objThatExist };
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: `const { id, state } = obj;` you never use `state` :p

Answer (score -1):

I solve this with nested each. I look every master objects and control that there are any same ids. if they are same values , push the zip into master object

**jQuery**

```
$.each(zips,(index,object)=>{
                var zipID=object.id;
                $.each(master,(indexMaster,objectMaster)=>{
                    if(zipID==objectMaster.id){
                        objectMaster['zip']=zipID
                    }
                })
            })
            console.log(master);
```

**JavaScript**

```
zips.forEach(index,object){
                var zipID=object.id;
                master.forEach(indexMaster,objectMaster){
                    if(zipID==objectMaster.id){
                        objectMaster['zip']=zipID
                    }
                }
            }
```