# Check if property of object exists within second object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I want to check if a property in a first object exists within a second object and change it's value if it's different, dinamically. The first object properties may change because it's created dinamically too, and the second object's properties are always the same.

The logic I need to find it's the following, but instead of doing it manually (checking every property and value with a different if clause) is there any way of creating a function that does this dinamically? I am using vanilla javascript

```
function mapObject2(obj1) {
    if (sessionStorage.getItem("obj2") != null) {
        var obj2 = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("obj2"))
        if (obj1.Color != obj2.Color) {
            obj1.Color = obj2.Color
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Object.assign()
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

```
function mapObject2(obj1) {
    if (sessionStorage.getItem("obj2") != null) {
        var obj2 = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("obj2"))
        Object.assign(obj1, obj2)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Is there any way to change the properties values only if the value of the first object is different than the one in the second one?

Comment: Why do you not want it to change it? If the property is the same, iit will be like it has not been changed at all.

Comment: Hi! Sorry I made a mistake in tje other reply and did not say that not *all* the properties in the fiest object exist in the second one, so some of the properties cannot be added.

Comment: If a property exists in obj1 but not in obj2, it will still remain in the resulting object.

Comment: Did you mean that some properties exist in obj2 but not in obj1 and you don't want to add them to the resulting object?

Comment: Yes sorrry I meant that, obj1 has properties I dont need in obj2

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40573555/merge-two-objects-but-only-existing-properties

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.assing` as @krasi said but the correct syntax is this

```
function mapObject2(obj1) {
    if (sessionStorage.getItem("obj2") != null) {
        var obj2 = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("obj2"))
        Object.assign(obj1, obj2)
    }
}
```

if you want to return a new object that is the merge of `obj1` and `obj2` you can do this

```
function mapObject2(obj1) {
    if (sessionStorage.getItem("obj2") != null) {
        const obj2 = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("obj2"))
        return {...obj1, ...obj2} 
        //or
        return Object.assign({}, obj1, obj2)
    }
   return obj1
}
```

```
function mapObject2(obj1) {
    if (sessionStorage.getItem("obj2") != null) {
        const obj2 = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("obj2"))
        Object.keys(obj1).forEach(k => {
          obj1[k] = obj2[k] || obj1[k]
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, the properties of the first object already exists within second one, I just want to change its value if the value of obj1.Property1 its different than obj2.Property1 (same as the if clause I put in my question). Is there any way to do so?

Comment: @TurtleCactus yes look at the first part of the answer `Object.assign(obj1, obj2)`

Comment: Hi! Sorry I made a mistake and did not say that not all the properties in the first object exist in the second one, so some of the properties shouldn't be added. Using object.assign is there any way to filter which properties do I copy to the second object?

Comment: Hi! I tried the code snipped and it copies the propertie but not it's value (if  obj1.Color: "blue", apparently if seems to copy Color in obj2 but not the value)